# How to edit WCF Message -  WCF message interceptors

Tags: wcf, message, memorystream

i'm having some problems implementing my WCF message interceptor.  Basically i'm accessing the body contents and performing an xslt tranform over the nodeset to sort it alphabethicaly.

I've tested the XSLT  stylesheet and it's working no problems.  I write the result of the transform to a MemoryStream object and then attempt to recreate the message from the stream contents.

I examine the resulting stream using either a StreamReader or by loading it into an XmlDocument and i can see the the xml it contains it my expected result from the XSLT transform.

My problem occures when i try to recreate the message!  I create an XmlReader based on the stream and use this as my body source for Message.CreateMessage(.....);

I cannot understand why i'm suddenly losing the "correct" contents in the stream when i could examine it and see a couple of statements earlier.

Help very much appreciated!

Full code of the method below:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,   IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {

        MessageBuffer msgbuf = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        Message tmpMessage = msgbuf.CreateMessage();
        XmlDictionaryReader xdr = tmpMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _compiledTransform.Transform(xdr,null,ms);

        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);

        MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(newStream);
        newStream.Position = 0;

        //To debug contents of the stream
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);
        var temp = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //At this point the XSLT tranforms has resulted in the fragment we want so all good!


        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        newStream.Position = 0;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(newStream,settings);
        reader.MoveToContent();

        //Reader seems to have lost the correct fragment!!! At least returned message does not contain correct fragment.
        Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, reader);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
        request = newMessage;

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the original and the transformed message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code works Griff. I've just plugged it into an existing an existing IDispatchMessageInspector implementation and it generated a good (transformed) message. I therefore suspect your problem lies elsewhere.

How are you establishing that the 'losing' the correct contents? Could whatever is inspecting the transformed message be reading the message prior to transformation by mistake?

Comment: Hi Ian,

To answer your question i'm using SoapUI  to send a soap request to the WCF service and also to capture the response! 

Also just in testing the the in built VStudio WCF test client  i don't get the expected result.

Could i be even more cheeky and  ask you to ping me on the version of the Inspector you plugged my code into?  I'm just wondering have i missed something stupid on my setup! 

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how the SoapUI could capture the _transformed_ request. Surely the SoapUI sends the original request, which gets transformed by your IDispatchMessageInspector before reaching your end-point. The response is then sent back to the SoapUI. But the UI has no visibility of the _transformed_ request (unless, perhaps, you're sending the request straight back as the response). So how do you know that the result of the transformation is being lost?

Comment: Code was actually working fine as suggested by Ian,  offline he graciously reviewed my code and with his help i determined that my test harness was at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to [correlate state with the BeforeSendReply method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest.aspx) then you should be returning null instead of the request reference.

Comment: yes agreed but that actually doesn't have a bearing on the issue i'm trying to solve!  thanks for your input all the same! i've made your suggested edit!